# Calling bash script that executes expect from within crontab

Tags: bash, ubuntu, cron, expect

I have a bash script that dumps some databases and gz them. Then it is calling expect script that transfers the file to the backup server using scp (specific user created especially for this purpose). Here is a bash script:

The `backupbases.sh` file:

```
#!/bin/bash
today=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")
dumpPath=/home/mbackup/
remotePass=thereispassword

for db in $(mysql -e 'show databases' -s --skip-column-names); do 
    dbname=$db
    if [ $dbname == "somedatabasename" ]; then
        fname=$today"-mr1a-"$db".gz"
        if [ -x $dumpPath$fname ]; then
            rm $dumpPath$fname
        fi
        mysqldump $db | gzip -c > $dumpPath$fname
        expect transfer.sh mbackup@server_address:/home/mbackup/$fname $dumpPath$fname $remotePass
        #rm $dumpPath$fname
    fi 
done
```

The `tansfer.sh` file:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

# connect via scp
set remote [lindex $argv 0]
set localpath [lindex $argv 1]
set password [lindex $argv 2]

spawn scp $localpath "$remote"
#######################
expect {
-re ".*es.*o.*" {
exp_send "yes\r"
exp_continue
}
-re ".*sword.*" {
exp_send "$password\r"
}
}
expect eof
```

One thing that bothers me is that the passwords is ended with a `#` sign which could be interpreted as a comment but calling `backupbases.sh` in console results in successful execution of bash/expect. Unfortunately when crontab calls it - only the bash part is executed. Database is dumped but file is not transferred. Ofcourse the password and server address are provided.

How to resolve it?

Comment: To solve crontab issues: try using full paths, as the crontab environment is not the same as the user one.

Comment: Using `/usr/bin/expect` didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Try to log the outputs of expect to a logfile so that perhaps you could know what's wrong with it. Also quote your arguments well to prevent splitting with spaces.

```
( expect transfer.sh "mbackup@server_address:/home/mbackup/$fname" "$dumpPath$fname" "$remotePass"; ) >/path/to/log/file 2>&1
```

By the way I recommend using a filename extension of `.exp` instead for expect scripts.

Comment: I used `"` and output to log file as you said but the file remains empty. When I called the script from console proper output appeard in the log file...